# Faulty DC preventing NTFRS replication

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

When adding a new DC (2012 R2) to a domain (2008) everything goes well except that it never advertises as DC. Doing a bit of diagnosis i found out that ntfrs replication never starts, consequently sysvol is never replicated thus preventing DC from going live. Event viewer says 3 possible reasons are:

[1] FRS can not correctly resolve the DNS name xxxx.local from this computer. 
 [2] FRS is not running on xxxx.local. 
 [3] The topology information in the Active Directory Domain Services for this replica has not yet replicated to all the Domain Controllers.

Looking at [1] and [2] it's pretty clear to me that its not the case but 3 is problable the cause. Checking all the dcs i found out that one of them is down. My question is pretty simple. If any of the DCs of the domain is down i'll never be able to add a new DC to domain? is there any workaround without fixing the problematic DC first? some way to disable the faulty dc without demoting it temporarily.

UPDATE + FIX:

> If any of the DCs of the domain is down i'll never be able to add a
>   new DC to domain?

Yes. I needed to fix the faulty DC before I could add a new one.

> ntfrs replication never starts

DNS and LDAP were being blocked by one of the sites. As a quick fix, i created a connection between different sites for replication. Instead of going straight to the PDC master, i made a connection 1 jump  away. Takes longer but worked while some folks were working on opening the required ports. It was hard to identify at start because all the process of installing and setting up a new DC on Ws2012 went ok including all the replication (except sysvol) but for some reason it was not trying automatically to use another DC to sync SYSVOL as it was unable to sync with PDC directly.

Comment: Why the heck are you using NTFRS replication to start with? You should have upgraded all of those to DFS-R years ago. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd640019%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Not my infrastructure. I was doing another job for my client but adding a new DC is preveting me from continuing. Arguing about ntfrs will not solve the problem.

Comment: `1.` **Looking at [1] and [2] it's pretty clear to me that its not the case** - Well it's not clear to us and knowing how you determined that would help us to stay focused on providing an accurate answer, because even though you state that 1 and 2 are OK, some of us are still going to ask about 1 and 2. `2.` If you know that one of the DC's is down and is preventing the promotion of the new DC, why aren't you addressing the down DC? That is surely causing problems unrelated to your issue.

Comment: Back to my initial question. I only wanted to know if one DC Global Catalog down in the domain would prevent a new DC Global Catalog to be added. The logs and diagnostics i presented are irrelevant if I knew the answer was clearly positive. I'm not asking how to fix actually. I just need a straight answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If any of the DCs of the domain is down i'll never be able to add a new DC to domain?

An unreachable domain controller doesn't necessarily prevent the addition of a new domain controller, unless the domain controller that's down provides the link between the new domain controller and the rest of the domain.

> is there any workaround without fixing the problematic DC first?

Given that this isn't really the problem you're having, I'll answer this a different way.  Your first troubleshooting steps are to:

1. Check that all your Active Directory services are running and not throwing errors, on both this server having the problem, and at least one of the domain controllers it's linked to.  (If you don't know what I mean when I say "linked," just read on, I'll get there shortly.)
2. Verify DNS.  Your new domain controller should have a different domain controller (that it can connect to) as its primary DNS server, and itself as a secondary or tertiary DNS server.  Make sure that's how it's configured, and make sure that you can actually connect to the other DNS configured servers.
3. Verify the links between your domain controllers.  The GUI application for this is called Active Directory Sites and Services, and will look a little like the screenshot below.  You need a link between the new domain controller and at least one other domain controller.  It should be automatically generated, but you can create one manually if needed.

[image]

After those basic steps, it's time to dig through the event logs, dcdiag and other Active Directory diagnostic/troubleshooting tools, which seems to be beyond the scope of your "simple question."

Comment: so you are saying this statement "The topology information in the Active Directory Domain Services for this replica has not yet replicated to all the Domain Controllers." not necessarily is the problem in this case since all the other DCs are working fine? I created a manual connection between the main DC to the new one. Either way when i restart the ntfrs i still get the same message. updated the question

Comment: @Bnlf Well, it probably *is* a topology problem, as in your new domain controller can't connect to any of the other domain controllers.

Comment: i added the new dc without any problems using the Active Directory Promote Wizard but after doing the diagnosis i realize the new dc was not advertising itself and the reason was the sysvol did not yet replicate but it was not a case of waiting. it wasn't able to replicate at all. the machine it is trying to replicate from is 100% fine so i assumed the number [3] on that event log list could be the reason.

Comment: @Bnlf Well, like I said, now it's time to troubleshoot with dcdiag and such.

Comment: `I created a manual connection between the main DC to the new one` - In probably 99% of DC deployments you probably shouldn't ever have to do that. Doing that to resolve the problem you're having is likely the wrong approach. It sounds like you're trying to screw in a screw with a hammer.

Comment: @joeqwerty Indeed, but I've found it a useful troubleshooting step.  The fact that it doesn't resolve the issue for our furry friend here definitely indicates there is more wrong than just an NTDS link.

Comment: Indeed. I never actually had to do it manually although it's an easy task. `The topology information in the Active Directory Domain Services for this replica has not yet replicated to all the Domain Controllers`. I assume adding a new dc using the wizard goes ok but between setting up and going online there's a huge gap. As everything else seems to have replicated ok and no other error shows up on logs I'm still assuming i wont be able to finish the promotion of any dc to the domain until all dcs know about the new guy.

Comment: Almost forgot to reply here. I've updated with what i did in order to fix everything. Your answer was not complete but definetely helped to solve the problem. Thanks